# Python 2.7 - How do I remove lines in a text file longer than x amount?

Tags: python-2.7

How do I remove lines in a text file longer than x amount? Then overwriting that file and saving only those lines that were x amount long.

```
f = open("file.txt","r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

f = open("file.txt","w")
for line in lines:
  if line!="ph5"+"\n":
    f.write(line)
f.close()
```

but don't work for me, because my strings contains "ph5", it's not only ph5 by itself

Comment: Why not use `len`? E.g. `if len(line) <= x: f.write(line)`. If you're set on checking the content of your lines (which isn't what your question asked..), you do that in Python by `"sub" in "substring"`

Comment: thanks worked great, how can i mark your answer as the correct one. and yes sorry i confused it with another thing i was wondering as well

Comment: No problem. You do that by clicking the check mark. Also, I'll update my answer with a real world example for comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To approach your problem:

1. Read in the lines of your file. ([`readlines`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readlines))
2. Filter your lines down to the ones shorter than or equal in length to `x`. ([`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter))
3. Overwrite your file. You might rejoin your lines into a string before doing so. ([`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join))
4. Always close the file when you're done.

**Edit**:

Now that you've figured out how to write it on your own, I'll offer an example of how this looks in the real world with a more Pythonic approach, so you can see the method I was suggesting as well.

```
# Open the file, read the lines into a list, and truncate the file.
file = open("file.txt", "r+")
lines = file.readlines()
file.seek(0)
file.truncate()

# Filter out lines longer than 42 characters and write to them the file.
lines = filter(lambda line: len(line) <= 42, lines)
file.writelines(lines)
file.close()
```